# Use value from resx file in selected language

Tags: asp.net, resx

I have a ASP.NET MVC Website.

I use resources files to translate the website using

```
@Html.Encode(Resources.MY_STRING)
```

But in some pages, I would like to display the text in all languages. Is it possible to do it with resx files ?

Here is a example of what I want to do :

```
@Html.Encode(Resources.MY_STRING, "en-US")
@Html.Encode(Resources.MY_STRING, "fr-FR")
```

Of course it doesn't like this but is there a way to do it using .resx files ? Or should but these texts in an other configuration file...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. But not as direct as your code.

```
CultureInfo userCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
string myString = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResource", "MyString", userCulture).ToString();
```

But maybe you just wanna store all languages for that particular case in one/all resources.

Comment: Thx for the example ! And yes it was stupid sorry, I can use 3 resource strings and set the same text for all languages...